# Date time picker

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, datetime

O código que tenho é este:

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
    language:  'pt',
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss',
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    minuteStep: 10
});
```

Eu quero que eu ao abrir o modal ele comece no dia de hoje ele esta a abrir em 1979.

Já tentei colocar `start: Date();` mas se eu fizer isso todos os dias antes do dia de hoje ficam desabilitados.

Comment: qual é o plugin utilizado, você poderia fornecer o link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após iniciar o plugin, adicione este código que irá atualizar a data para a atual:

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

**Exemplo:**

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
   language:  'pt',
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss',
   autoclose: true,
   todayBtn: true,
   minuteStep: 10
}).datetimepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

**De outra forma**, você pode usar o evento `show`, que irá pegar a data atual assim que o calendário for aberto:

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
   language:  'pt',
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss',
   autoclose: true,
   todayBtn: true,
   minuteStep: 10
}).on("show", function(){
   $(this).datetimepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicione `useCurrent: false` no seu código, que deve aparecer

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
    language:  'pt',
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss',
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    minuteStep: 10,
useCurrent: true
});
```

Outra solução, é você setar o campo... assim que abrir o modal.

o seu modal tem um id, certo ? geralmente abrimos o modal assim `$("#meumodal").modal();`

Assim que você abrir o modal, você pode setar o valor do campo dentro desse modal....

```
$("#meumodal").find('.form_datetime').val(NOVA_DATA);
```

A variavel nova_data, você pode criar ela com javascript, ou com php.... um tecnica que uso muito é, criar um input

`<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" id="data_time_atual>`

Com isso fica bem mais facil pegar a hora com javascript

```
var hora = $("#data_time_atual").val();
```

agora é só setar o NOVA_DATA

```
 var hora = $("#data_time_atual").val();
 $("#meumodal").find('.form_datetime').val(hora );
```

Aqui tambpem tem o link da documentação
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/